# Java applet visual editor gui

Tags: java, user-interface, drag-and-drop, applet, editor

I am developing a Java applet for a University course. What is the best visual editor for GUI components in developing a Java applet? I do not have much experience with visual editors other than Microsoft technologies, what is going on behind the scenes with a Java applet visual editor?

How about Eclipse?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend NetBeans IDE. It's an all-in-one solution for Java development and they've been doing great things with visual editors for years.

http://netbeans.org/

You can try Eclipse as well, I use both, but I find NetBeans better for visual work, and Eclipse better for web application development.